# Knockout.js HTML template not responding to edits?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I don't even know how to describe this, it's so utterly confusing I have no clue where to begin.

I have a Knockout template stored in a `<script type="text/html">` tag in my document. I want to edit this template. So I edit it and save it. I notice via the Web Development Tools that the change has taken place by inspecting the script tag and its value.

When Knockout.js applies the template to the DOM, **the template has not been changed**. In fact, I can entirely remove the template and Knockout magically places the old version of the template in there - as if it's caching it somehow.

I have tried Firefox and Google Chrome, both with cache resets.

For what it's worth, I am also using Require.js, however, I am unsure how this would affect anything as the templates I am trying to use with Knockout are embedded inline in the page, not loaded as an external file.

I suspect that either Knockout.js or Require.js is causing this, but I cannot figure out how.

#### Template in question (in create.blade.php):

```
<!-- Any edits or changes made to the following template will not be reflected when Knockout.js uses it, instead it appears to be 'caching' an old version of this template -->
<script type="text/html" id="image-file-template">
    <div data-bind="attr: { 'data-index': $index }, visible: $root.visibleTemplate() == ko.unwrap($index)">
        <h2 data-bind="text: original_name"></h2>
        <form>
            <ul class="container">
                <li class="grid-4">
                    <label>
                        <p>Title</p>
                        <input type="text" name="title" data-bind="value: title" />
                    </label>
                </li>

                <!-- Snip -->
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</script>
```

#### Loading of my Knockout ViewModel in the DOM (create.blade.php)

```
<script data-main="/src/js/common" src="/src/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(['common'], function() {
        require(['knockout', 'viewmodels/UploadViewModel'], function(ko, UploadViewModel) {
            ko.applyBindings(new UploadViewModel());
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### How knockout selects my template on the ViewModel (UploadViewModel.js)

```
    // Declare which template to use when a file is uploaded
    self.templateObjectType = function (uploadedFile) {
        var uploadedFileType = uploadedFile.type();
        if (uploadedFileType == 1) {
            return 'image-file-template'; // This is being called, I can confirm via the debugger, but the template being returned appears cached?
        } else if (uploadedFileType == 2) {
            return 'gif-file-template';
        } else if (uploadedFileType == 3) {
            return 'audio-file-template';
        } else if (uploadedFileType == 4) {
            return 'video-file-template';
        } else if (uploadedFileType == 5) {
            return 'document-file-template';
        }
    };
```

#### My Require.js config (common.js)

```
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    baseUrl: '/src/js',
    paths: {
        'text': 'lib/requirejs-text',
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.9.1',
        'jquery.ui' : 'lib/jquery-ui.min',
        "jquery.fracs": 'lib/jquery.fracs-0.15.0',
        'dropzone': 'lib/dropzone',
        "jquery.throttle-debounce": 'lib/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min',
        'knockout': 'lib/knockout-3.2.0.debug',
        'ko.mapping': 'lib/knockout.mapping-latest',
        'ko.postbox': 'lib/knockout-postbox',
        'd3': 'lib/d3',
        'moment': 'lib/moment',
        'sticky': 'lib/sticky'
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.fracs": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.throttle-debounce": ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

Has anyone ever encountered anything remotely like this?

Comment: The issue you describe is intriguing. Can you recreate this in jsfiddle? Here's a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/samsceuc/) you can fork that uses requirejs if it helps you recreate this issue.

Comment: I faced an issue similar to this once, in the end it turned out I was using the same id for two different templates.